# Is it possible to get a new Indian evisa despite valid prior tourist visa in now-expired US passport?

Tags: india, us-citizens, visas-on-arrival, e-visas

I have a valid (till feb 2018) 10 year, multiple entry, Indian tourist visa in an **expired US passport**. That visa was issued in 2010.

As required, I obtained a  **new current US passport**, so new it's got nothing on it yet. We're traveling to India in 3 weeks.

My spouse has applied for an evisa as the consulate's representatives said they weren't sure we'd get a normal tourist visa in time.

When we get to India, I'd prefer to be allowed to go through the same immigration lines as evisa holders, both at the exit and entry as I'm wheelchair-bound and would appreciate having my husband at hand in the same line.

**Can I get an evisa despite the existence of a valid tourist visa**? That older visa is after all in an expired passport. Cox and Kings has no idea and referred me to the Bureau of Immigration in India, who do not always reply to email.

Answer (score 1):

Per [Immihelp](https://www.immihelp.com/nri/indiavisa/transfer-of-india-visa-new-passport.html), you should still be able to use your old visa as long as you bring both old and new passports:

> If you have a valid visa in your old passport that has expired, your
>   visa is still valid. You can travel to India using both the old and
>   the new passports. However, it is recommended to get it transferred to
>   the new passport to avoid hassles in case you forget to carry the old
>   passport while traveling.
>
> If you have received a new passport since you got the India visa, you
>   can get the visa transferred to the new passport. **However, the visa
>   can only be transferred to a passport of the same nationality**. I.e.,
>   you can transport from old the U.S. passport to the new U.S. passport.
>   The name on both passports must match.

However, if you want to have a new e-Visa to be in the same immigration line as your husband, the India e-Visa [page](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/evisa/tvoa.html) doesn't list any restrictions on applying for a **new** e-Visa even though you have an existing Tourist visa in your old passport. This [page](https://www.bankbazaar.com/visa/e-visa.html) also lists the full requirements:

> The following eligibility conditions apply when you opt for an e-visa:
>
> - It is issued to travelers who visit a country for the purpose of visiting friends and relatives, recreational activities, medical
>     treatment or short term business visit.
> - The passport of an applicant must have minimum six months validity from the date of visa application.
> - The passport should have minimum two blank pages for stamping by the Immigration Officer.
> - Applicants should have return tickets ready to go back after staying at a destination for a previously specified duration of time.
> - Children and infants should have separate e-visas and passports.
>
> The following documents are required for applying for an e-visa:
>
> - A valid passport with a minimum validity for 6 months.
> - Passport size photographs.